# ¿Cómo gestiono evento de swipe en Typescript?

Tags: typescript, eventos, scroll

Estoy haciendo una aplicación amateur y gestiono el *scroll* mediante el teclado en vista normal. Pero como necesitaré hacerlo en un móvil, en la vista móvil de chrome como lo puedo gestionar para saber cuando el scroll está al final o al principio?

En vista normal lo hago con `keyCodes.KEY_UP` y `keyCodes.KEY_DOWN`, existe alguna `keyCode` equivalente para el *swipe* del móvil?

Y otra pregunta, como hago un evento o algo para saber si me muevo hacia abajo o hacia arriba, es para saber cuando estoy arriba de todo poner una flecha hacia abajo y cuando llego al final poner una flecha hacia arriba.

Comment: ¿Qué es lo que quieres hacer? Es decir, el hacer scroll en un navegador es algo de lo que se encarga el navegador, no tienes que hacerlo tú a menos que quieras precisamente evitarlo

Comment: Por definición `keyCodes` se refiere a teclas del teclado, por lo que nada tiene que ver el swipe  con esta variable.

Comment: Esther y @Esther_5, parece que tienes dos cuentas diferentes. Lee [He creado dos cuentas accidentalmente, ¿cómo puedo combinarlas?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts) si quieres juntarlas :)

Answer (score 0):

Si lo que quieres hacer es saber si tu scroll está al principio o no (o en cualquier posición) tienes esta instrucción:

```
var scrollPos = window.scrollY || 
                window.scrollTop ||
                document.getElementsByTagName("html")[0].scrollTop;
```

En la variable *scrollPos* tendrás cuánto se ha desplazado (scroll) el usuario desde el top